# In an Shiny App, I want a plot to update, based on the search results in a datatable.

Tags: r, shiny

Say I have a Shiny app with a datatable and a plot. I want to be able to search/filter the datatable, and have a plot reflect the results.

How do I do this? Is this even possible? Is there any way to output the filtered datatable to an object I can use?

Here is a basic shiny application which does not work.

```
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  plotOutput('plot1')

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars,filter = 'top')
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(input$mytable$wt, input$mytable$mpg)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have edited your code a bit since your way has some mistakes as pointed out by @r2evans.

Anyways, you can get the filtered rows of a datatable using `input$tableId_rows_all`. It gives the indices of rows on all pages (after the table is filtered by the search strings).

In my code `filtered_table()` gives you a dataframe object after all search filters are applied. `output$test` shows this table in real-time.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test"),
  plotOutput('plot1')

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  mc <- head(mtcars) # could be reactive in real world case

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mc, filter = 'top')
  })

  filtered_table <- reactive({
    req(input$mytable_rows_all)
    mc[input$mytable_rows_all, ]  
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(filtered_table()$wt, filtered_table()$mpg, col = "red", lwd = 10)
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    filtered_table()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know about `_rows_selected`, `_rows_all`, and all, well listed here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html#datatables-information. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Tour `input$mytable` reference in `output$plot1` is just a string, not a frame like you'd hope, so this needs to be replaced. You can hard-code `mtcars`, but hard-coding data doesn't really lend to an extensible and interactive experience.
- Additionally, since you are going to be showing the same data in two different blocks (`$mytable` and `$plot1`), I suggest breaking the data into its own reactive block and referencing that block in the others.
- Lastly, I think it's good defensive practice to use `req(...)` in blocks so that they do not try to execute before the data is available (common when reactive pathways are unclear or the inputs are not set yet).

Try this:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  plotOutput('plot1')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydat <- reactive({
    # eventually you'll support filtering here
    mtcars
  })    

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(mydat())
    datatable(mydat(), filter = 'top')
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(mydat())
    plot(mydat()$wt, mydat()$mpg)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: working shiny example]